# Speeding Up Image Loading from DB

Tags: php, sql, performance, wordpress

I'm loading 9 images from a database and my syntax looks roughly like this:

```
<img src="image_loader.php?id=4"></img>
```

My PHP for image_loader.php looks like:

```
<?php
    /* I set up my connection using mysql_connect and mysql_select_db */

    $query = sprintf("SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE id='".$_GET["id"]."'");
    $result = mysql_query($query, $con);
    mysql_close($con);

    if (!$result) {
        // no result
    }
    else {
        $row = mysql_fetch_row($result); 
        header('Content-type: image/png');
        echo $row[0];
        mysql_free_result($result);
        }
?>
```

Each image is about 10-13k but the bunch seems to be loading very slow.  I realize that there is some bottle-necking in the number of requests a browser can execute at a time but the wait times seem to be gratuitous.

Any suggestions on how to get images loaded from a database fast?

Also, and this is almost a separate question, but is it possible to instruct a browser (or server) to cache images with now .gif/.png/.jpg srcs?  It seems that Firefox does and Chrome doesn't, but I'm not certain of this.

[image]

Comment: If your cache header is correctly set and the URL don't changes, images should be cached. If your problem is on the bandwidth and you frequently send the same images, you should consider combining them so that there is only one query to server (really depends on the images, though, it pays for a dozen of small images for example).

Comment: It is possible that your browser isn't caching the images because they have query strings, could could consider linking to something like `image_loader\4.jpg` and using URL rewriting.  You could also "tile" the images as dystroy suggests using a technique similar to the one outlines [here](http://www.guistuff.com/css/css_imagetech1.html).

Comment: I'd also consider whether storing images in a database makes the most sense.  It may, but it should be seriously considered, as giving each image a unique filename in the filesystem and storing ***that*** in the database will often be faster.  You would gain additional speed if you could request that file ***directly*** from the client as opposed to requesting a generic PHP script that does an `fopen()`

Comment: That's true but this shouldn't even be measurable in such a case (for a normal database).

Comment: For a local database, I agree, the difference would probably be very small.  But for a database on a separate machine, especially a shared database server (this arrangement is common with some hosts now, GoDaddy, etc), I could see the various delays adding up.

Comment: @jedwards I should add I am operating on a shared machine on DreamHost.  What I'm coding more or less requires that I store the images in a database, I suppose ultimately if I can't get this delay cut I may need to consider saving files off, but I'd like to avoid it if at all possible.  It creates another layer of complexity.

Comment: @vpiTriumph, is the hostname in your `mysql_connect()` function localhost or something else?  (If its something else, what exactly it is doesn't matter).  If its not localhost, I'd suggest instrumenting your `image_loader.php` code with timestamps to locate the delay?  My guess is that it'll be in the query.

Comment: I wonder if that's the root of my problem.  DreamHost keeps their MySQL servers separate from their web servers per their [help](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/MySQL).

Comment: @jedwards what I ultimately determined is that DreamHost is notoriously slow for MySQL (a lot of this is because the db is not on the same server as the hosting) and the result of this is that a lot of frameworks, for example Drupal, that execute a lot of queries run slow... slow... slow...  I was able to work around my problem by saving images off to a folder instead of into my database.  If you want to type up an answer that hits on some of your suggestions I'll give you the points for it!

Comment: Happy you were able to find a work around and happy to have helped. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd first consider whether storing images in a database makes the most sense. It may, but it should be seriously considered, as giving each image a unique filename in the filesystem and storing ***that*** in the database will often be faster.

You would gain additional speed if you could request that file ***directly*** from the client as opposed to requesting a generic PHP script that does some sort of `fopen()`-style abstraction.

In order to narrow down the source of delay, it first might be helpful to check whether your database is hosted on the same server as your webserver.  One indication that it is not hosted locally but on a remote database server is to check the host string you're providing in the `mysql_connect()` call.  `localhost` would suggest its local, something else would suggest it's not.  As a note, many shared hosted services (e.g. GoDaddy) split their database server from the webserver.

For a better idea of the source of the delay, I'd suggest instrumenting your `image_loader.php` code with timestamps to locate the delay? My guess is that it'll be in the query.

If the delay ***is*** in your query, you will want to limit the number of queries you make.  A strategy that allows you to make one query instead of 9 would limit the impact any webserver-to-database server delay.